# Does Nx support caching symbolic links?

Tags: npm, caching, symlink, nrwl

I have a Nx monorepo project which has a `node_modules/.bin` folder with content like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x   84 demo  staff   2688 Dec  8 13:29 .
drwxr-xr-x  997 demo  staff  31904 Dec  8 13:29 ..
lrwxr-xr-x    1 demo  staff     20 Dec  8 13:29 JSONStream -> ../JSONStream/bin.js
lrwxr-xr-x    1 demo  staff     18 Dec  8 13:29 acorn -> ../acorn/bin/acorn
lrwxr-xr-x    1 demo  staff     29 Dec  8 13:29 ag -> ../@asyncapi/generator/cli.js
```

This folder is also configured to be cached.

After running a build, when looking at the corresponding cached content in `.nx/cache/.../outputs/node_modules/.bin`, the symbolic links are gone:

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 demo  staff    251 Aug 25 11:27 JSONStream
-rwxr-xr-x    1 demo  staff     60 Aug 25 11:26 acorn
-rwxr-xr-x    1 demo  staff   7780 Aug 25 11:26 ag
```

When a process is running `ag` after the cache is restored, an error occurs:

```
REDACTED/node_modules/.bin/ag [..additional parameters..]

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './package.json'
Require stack:
- /REDACTED/node_modules/.bin/ag
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/REDACTED/node_modules/.bin/ag:8:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/REDACTED/node_modules/.bin/ag'
  ]
}
```

When restoring the symbolic link everything works as expected.

I would expect, that the Nx caching mechanism is preserving the symbolic links. Is it expected to do so?

Comment: This seems to be related: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/19502